# How to switch from leqno to reqno?

Tags: equations, numbering, amsmath, amsart

I'm using a template I got off Keith Conrad's website (https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/math2784f14/papertemplate.tex.html) for a class and I'd like to make the equation numeration appear on the right side. However, when I remove [leqno] from the command

```
\usepackage[leqno]{amsmath}
```

nothing happens, and when I change it to reqno the file doesn't compile, because of some "option clash" (when I change the package from amsmath to mathtools the error is not thrown, however the numbering isn't affected either). What do I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not advisable to link to templates or documents at places other than, for example, CTAN. But I understand that it is not feasable to paste the whole template here. So, here it goes:

The `\documentclass` used by the template is `amsart` which defaults to its option `leqno`. In order to avoid the option clash, you need to load the `\documentclass` with the option `reqno` as well.

So, you need to do two things:

1. add the option `reqno` to the options of the `amsart` class

   ```
   \documentclass[12pt,letterpaper,reqno]{amsart}
   ```
2. and change the option `leqno` to `reqno` for the package `amsmath`.

   ```
   \usepackage[reqno]{amsmath}
   ```

This should solve you problem and switch the equation numbers to the right.

Comment: Thanks, it worked! And what were to happen if I were to change amsmath to mathtools? I heard the latter is basically an improved version of the former, so it shouldn't break anything, right?

Comment: You can try, but only because it is said to be an "improved version" does not necessarily mean that it won't break anything. It *could* work, though, since it internally loads `amsmath` anyways.